# How to get zip code from current location in iOS using google api

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-places-api, zipcode

I am able to find actual location in autofill search textfield. But i cant able to find zip code from this code. Please give me a solution.

```
-(void)googleAPICallWithText:(NSString*)strData {


strData = [strData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSLog(@"Value of allSelectedItems = %@", strData);


//google api url
NSString   *web_service_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@json?input=%@&sensor=%@&key=%@",GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_URL,strData,@"true",GOOGLE_API_KEY];

NSMutableString *reqData = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    id jsonDta= [reqData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString   *jsonRepresantationFormat = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonDta encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self WebsewrviceAPICall:web_service_URL webserviceBodyInfo:jsonRepresantationFormat];
}

 -(void)WebsewrviceAPICall:(NSString *)serviceURL  webserviceBodyInfo:(NSString *)bodyString {
self.connectionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(cancelInsingAPICall) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serviceURL]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

if( self.connection ){
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements aren't restricted to using Google's API, you can use CoreLocation instead. When you get the location in the delegate's callback, you can reverse geocode the location object into a placemark, which contains the zip code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *current = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:current completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *zip = placemark.postalCode;

             // do stuff with zip code
         } else {
             // geocode failed
         }
     }];
}
```